# Paint App, JQuery mobile - Object Has No Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm really pretty new to code.  I'm trying to make a paint app that will work on desktop and mobile.  I had it working fine on desktop using JavaScript but then to get it to work on mobile it seemed like JQuery mobile was a recommended method.  I'm converting it to JQuery and had the maint working with .mousedown, .mouseup, etc. but when I changed to to .vmousedown, .vmouseup, etc. to have it work with touch I get an error which I can't seem to resolve.

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'vmousedown'

I've seen other people with similar issues but I'm having a hard time making it work for me.

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mquickel/dehAD/79/

HTML Snippet

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="colorCSS2.css">


    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body data-role="page">
<div id="container">
    <div id="sketch" data-role="content">
        <canvas id="paint" style="z-index: 0; position:absolute;" height="600px" width="600px"></canvas> 
        <canvas id="layer2" style="z-index: 1; position:absolute;" height="600px" width="600px"></canvas> 
    </div>
```

JS Snippet

```
    document.getElementById( "container" ).onmousedown = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    }

    var layer2 = document.getElementById("layer2");
    var ctx2 = layer2.getContext("2d");
    var imageObj = new Image();
    /* Loading the Image*/
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        ctx2.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-P5ucC3TjCLU/UjHE0rENTaI/AAAAAAAAAts/mH2A_OORkQY/s800/color.png';


(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('paint');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imageObj = new Image();

    var cont = document.getElementById('container');
    var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};
    var last_mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

    /* Mouse Capturing Work */

    $(cont).mousemove (function(e) {
    last_mouse.x = mouse.x;
    last_mouse.y = mouse.y;

     mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
     mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    });


    /* Drawing on Paint App */
    ctx.lineWidth = 20;
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = brushColor; 


    $(cont).vmousedown(function(e) {
    console.log("hi");
    $(cont).vmousemove (onPaint);
    });


     $(cont).vmouseup (function() {
     console.log("up");
     $(cont).unbind ('vmousemove', onPaint);
     });

    var onPaint = function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(last_mouse.x, last_mouse.y);
        ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    };

}());
```

Comment: why not just `$('#container')` ?

Comment: Use `$('#container').on('vmousedown vmouseup touchstart touchend', function () { code }):`. These events `'vmousedown vmouseup touchstart touchend` are the same, but touchstart and touchend are triggered before virtual mouse events.

Comment: Thank you so much - with a little bit of effort I got it worked based off your feedback.  Both mouse and touch work.  There is however one last thing I'd like to resolve for now when it comes to touch.  The paint stroke tops where I let off with my finger but when I press down again it connects where the mouse left off and the new location.  I'm not sure what the issue is since it seems to be working with the mouse ok.  http://jsfiddle.net/mquickel/n5ND9/14/

Comment: In the demo, you're not use `vmouseup` or `touchend`. Try refreshing x and y values on those events.