# drawing a smooth line on html5 canvas for mobile app using jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, canvas, cordova

I am trying to draw on canvas, like drawing using pencil tool in the paint using jquery mobile.

I searched for many links and most of them were for the desktop, i tried to implement the same logic for the mobile app, i am able to obtain only the click events but not able to draw the line on the canvas.

This is what i was trying to implement on the mobile http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/dQppK/23/

This is my code

```
$(document).on(
        'pageshow',
        '#canvaspage',
        function() {
            var painting = false;
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            // ctx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
            // ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
            // ctx.drawImage(icons-18-black.png)

            ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
            ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.8;

            var imageObj = new Image();

            imageObj.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width * 0.8,
                        ctx.canvas.height * 0.7);
            };
            imageObj.src = 'Image.png';

//          c.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
            $("#myCanvas").on("touchstart",function(e){
                painting = true;
                e.preventDefault();

                ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
                lastX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                lastY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

            });

//          c.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
            $("#myCanvas").on("touchend",function(e){
                painting = false;

            });

//          c.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {

            $("#myCanvas").on("touchmove",function(e){  

                  if (painting) {

                        mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
                        mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

                        // find all points between        
                        var x1 = mouseX,
                            x2 = lastX,
                            y1 = mouseY,
                            y2 = lastY;


                        var steep = (Math.abs(y2 - y1) > Math.abs(x2 - x1));
                        if (steep){
                            var x = x1;
                            x1 = y1;
                            y1 = x;

                            var y = y2;
                            y2 = x2;
                            x2 = y;
                        }
                        if (x1 > x2) {
                            var x = x1;
                            x1 = x2;
                            x2 = x;

                            var y = y1;
                            y1 = y2;
                            y2 = y;
                        }

                        var dx = x2 - x1,
                            dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1),
                            error = 0,
                            de = dy / dx,
                            yStep = -1,
                            y = y1;

                        if (y1 < y2) {
                            yStep = 1;
                        }

                        lineThickness = 5 - Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) *(x2-x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2-y1))/10;
                        if(lineThickness < 1){
                            lineThickness = 1;   
                        }
                        alert(painting +" " +x1 +" "+x2);
                        for (var x = x1; x < x2; x++) {

//                          alert(x +" "+ y +" "+ lineThickness);
                            if (steep) {
                                ctx.fillRect(y, x, lineThickness , lineThickness );
                            } else {
                                ctx.fillRect(x, y, lineThickness , lineThickness );
                            }
                            alert(steep);
                            error += de;
                            if (error >= 0.5) {
                                y += yStep;
                                error -= 1.0;
                            }
                        }



                        lastX = mouseX;
                        lastY = mouseY;

                    }



//              ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 75);
                e.preventDefault();
            }, false);
        });
```

In the above code i am able to obtain all the touch events but the unable to draw the line.

How can i draw the lines on the canvas??..

Thanks:)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166529/paint-app-jquery-mobile-object-has-no-method

Answer (score 0):

You can use sketch.js (http://intridea.github.io/sketch.js/) with a small modification to make it work on mobile. The modification is given in the comment by leonth here: https://github.com/intridea/sketch.js/issues/1; you basically add 3 lines to the plugin on the mousedown/touchstart event:

```
switch (e.type) {
    case 'mousedown':
    case 'touchstart':          
      if (this.painting) {    //add
        this.stopPainting();  //add
      }                       //add
      this.startPainting();
      break;
...
```

> Here is a **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/4hfkb/6/)**, try it from mobile device.

Comment: it is working but i am getting the following error `12-12 06:27:04.905: E/Web Console(31748): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/sketch.js:106
`  also whenever i try to draw the new sketch, it starts from the end point of previous sketch. how to avoid it?

Comment: When i visit the fiddle on my nexus 7, it seems to work fine.  If you are compiling it to a native app, someone else will have to jump in as I don't have experience with that.